# Django: Loss of float precision on save()

Tags: python, django, command-line, django-models, floating-point

My Django object `FloatField`s are being rounded down after I call `save()` after setting the values on the command line.

Example:

```
object = Model.objects.get(id=1)
object.floatfield = 23.99
object.floatfield 
23.99
object.save()
object =  Model.objects.get(id=1)
object.floatfield
23.0
```

What am I missing? What is causing this?

EDIT: Model is:

```
class AbstractModel(models.Model): 
    class Meta: 
        abstract = True 
    float = models.FloatField(default=-1)

class Model(AbstractModel):
    pass
```

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Was it an IntegerField before? Did you migrate it if you made a change?

Comment: It was an IntegerField before, yes. It is still in development so I rolled back the previous migration, deleted the old migration file, then `makemigration` and `migrate`

Comment: What kind of field is is not in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Django model and the database table are a bit out of whack.  You can check this by looking at the definition of the `Model.float` column in your database.  Without seeing your migrations I can't tell exactly what is going on.

You say in the comments that you rolled back the migration, deleted the migration file and then tried to migrate again.  I recommend you give that another shot but this time `DROP` the table in the database before you `makemigration`.  Just let Django recreate the table, probably easier then trying to figure out exactly what is going on.